# Idiomatic sbt custom incremental work criteria

Tags: scala, sbt

I'd like to have my compile task depend on a task `myTask` that is fairly expensive but should only run if a custom metric has changed since the last time it was run. Let's say I have a function `myCriterion : State => String` that returns a canonical representation of my custom criterion.

Ideally, I would like compile to depend on `myTask onlyIf myCriterion changed` or something along those lines. I see a bunch of stuff around `Tracked.inputChanged` and `FilesInfo.*` that seems relevant, but I can't find any indication of how to use them. Behind the scenes, I'd like `myTask` to run `myCriterion`, check it against the cached version on disk if it's present, and if they match, to do nothing at all. If they don't match, I'd like it to run the logic of `myTask` and then write the current output of `myCriterion` to the cache so we don't perform the task unnecessarily next time around (since it will just produce the same output each time). The compile should obviously happen regardless of whether `myTask` turns into a nop or not.

Answer (score 0):

I think I've figured out how to use `Tracked`, for what it's worth: if I write `Tracked.inputChanged(somePath) { case (changed, state: String) => if (changed) ... }` and apply the result of that to a `String` (with an `Equiv[String]` instance in scope) then it does the change checking for me. I'm still curious about an idiomatic way to relate tasks to this kind of pattern though.

Comment: Tracked is what sbt uses internally, but it isn't an API I consider good or idiomatic and hence it isn't advertised as usable.  That might be partly to a lack of something like `deriving`, but also because it isn't much of an abstraction.  Better ideas are welcome.